# .htaccess redirecting to `www.www.example.com`

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5

I'm building a site using `Laravel5` and I'm having an issue with my `.htaccess` file redirecting to `https://www.www.example.com`.  I was trying to force redirect from `http` to `https` and now I'm getting duplicate `www.` in the URL.

Accessing the site via `https://example.com` (without `www`) works fine however.

Here is my `.htaccess` file contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectoryIndex public/index.php public/index.html

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone provide a suggestion on what needs to change to force a redirect to `https` while allowing the following URLs to access the site and redirect to `https://www.example.com`:

- `www.example.com`
- `https://example.com`
- `https://www.example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `http://example.com`

Comment: You still want `http://www.example.com` to function as is?

Comment: well I'd like to have that redirect to `https` as well. I'll update  my OP, thanks

Comment: ok for `https` URL do you always want `www` to be present? e.g. all of these URLs should be redirected to `https://www.example.com` ?

Comment: yes, that is correct.  I just updated the OP to reflect that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # add www with http -> https
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing to avoid old cache.

Comment: Yes, that seems to have fixed my issues.  Thank you!